# can't edit through vim in eclipse after installing eclim

Tags: eclipse, vim

I successfully install eclim following the instructs by [enter link description here](http://eclim.org/eclimd.html#headed-eclipse-server)

And I can access eclipse feature in vim.

But even after I started eclim in eclipse
Window ‣ Show View ‣ Other ‣ Eclim ‣ eclimd

I cann't edit my files in eclipse through vim

Comment: Did you right-click the file to be edited and select _Open With > Vim_? What exactly do you mean you can't edit files through Vim? Maybe a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: The vrapper plugin in Eclipse allows you to use vim keystrokes inside the Eclipse editor. This is not exactly what you are asking for, but is a solution that allows you to edit a file in Eclipse using vim.